# Font width returns incorrect values

Tags: python, pygtk

The following code should return the width in pixels of the character 'a' in the default font; it doesn't:

```
import pygtk
gtk.require20()
import gtk

t = gtk.TextView()
print t.get_style().get_font().width("w") # Always returns -6
```

Comment: t.get_style.string_width("test") doesn't work either as it only returns 6.

Answer (score 1):

`gtk.Style.get_font()` is deprecated, as evidenced by the DeprecationWarning you get when you try to call it; I assume that's why it's not working. On my PyGTK there isn't any such function as `gtk.Style.string_width()`.

You should use Pango:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require20()
import gtk

t = gtk.TextView()
print t.create_pango_layout('w').get_pixel_size()
```